# Call-return semantic in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

As we know, C#'s built-in thread model does not support the passing of return values from one thread back to the "parent" thread that created it. I’m implementing a small compiler for matrix calculations in C#. Compiler generates IL code using `System.Reflection.Emit` name space. For this compiler I’m planning to implement call-return semantics. Can somebody point out to me a suitable technique to implement call-return semantics using C# `Thread` (or any other technique)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Task<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx):

> **Task<TResult> Class**
>
> Represents an asynchronous operation that can return a value.

*Example 1: Start a new task and wait for the task to complete*

```
var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult());

task.Wait();
Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

*Example 2: Start a new task and continue with action when the task completes*

```
var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult());

task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
});
```

Comment: And when you want to parallelize over matrices/ arryas etc, also take a look at the Task Parallel Library chapter Data Parallelism (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A little more detail would be useful but...

In order to get a "return value" back to the parent thread you need some rendez-vous mechanism. It can be simple (the parent thread blocks and waits for completion) or it can be more complicated (using the async pattern (BeginXxx EndXxx, like BeginSend EndSend) or continuations, for example).

In the simplest case, an idea might be to wrap your "concurrent call" in a class which hold the thread and a field for the return value (you might want to make this class generic).
For the more complicated (and efficient!) implementations using asynchrony, I really suggest to look into the TPL (.NET 4 parallel library). In particular, look at Task.ContinueWith: if in your compiler you are able to transform call-return to a concatenation of continuations it would be a great implementation!

More details: suppose you have this sequence:

```
Matrix a = blah; 
Matrix b = ConcurrentOperationOnMatrix(a); 
// this must block, wait for the prev line to complete
AnotherOperationOnMatrix(b);
```

You can trasform it in a list of continuations:

```
ConcurrentOperationOnMatrix(a, b => AnotherOperationOnMatrix(b));
```

Each function never returns, it just call the rest of the program when it finishes. Look into F# async workflows, they use the same technique.

Comment: More details: suppose you have this sequence: 
Matrix a = blah
Matrix b = ConcurrentOperationOnMatrix(a);
AnotherOperationOnMatrix(b); // this must block, wait for the prev line to complete

You can trasform it in a list of continuations:
ConcurrentOperationOnMatrix(a, b => AnotherOperationOnMatrix(b));

Each function never returns, it just call the rest of the program when it finishes. Look into F# async workflows, they use the same technique.

Comment: Edit your answer instead of adding a comment. This makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the IAsyncResult that the .Net framework uses for all it's callback style programming.  Basically you can use return an IAsyncResult when you make your function call.  You can then use the AsyncWaitHandle property to signal back to your caller that the result is ready, and pass the result in the AsyncState property.

This is a clean way with predefined classes to do what you need.  You could implement some kind of signal and then implement something like a shared variable to pass back the result.  This might help you if you need to try and get interlocked code to work as performantly as possible.

Comment: I guess that some of the new code in .Net will probably use async from c# now, Any of the methods that start with "Begin..." use this.